# Is $g$ continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose  that  $f$ is  continuous  on $\mathbb{R}, \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} f(x) = - \infty $ and $ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}f(x) = + \infty $. define  $g$ be setting 
$$g(x)= \sup\{t : f(t) <x \} \ \text{for} \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$
Now my question is that

Is  $g$ continuous  ?

my attempt  : No ,  $g $ need not be  continious

take $f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x < 1,\\
-x+2,& 1 \le x \le 2, \\
x-2, & x > 2\end{cases}$.

Then  $g(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \le 0,\\
x+2, & x > 0\end{cases}$.

graph :[image]

Comment: It has to hold for *all* such functions $f$, not simply a particular one like you have.

Comment: okss @EeveeTrainer..im thinking

Comment: Your $f$ does not satisfy the conditions...

Comment: @copper.hat if  $x<0$ then $ f(x)$  will tend  to negative

Comment: To be fair, @copper.hat, no function (as far as I know) satisfies the conditions as written. :p Probably a typo somewhere.

Comment: @jasmine As $x \to -\infty$, $f(x) = |x| \to +\infty$. Consider increasingly negative values of $x$ - $-10, -100, -1000, -10000$, $f$ maps each to their positive version. Not that this helps much since you need to generalize beyond a specific $f$ but I figured I'd point that out.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: I missed the missing $-$ on the first limit!

Comment: why im getting  lots of downvote ??

Comment: I have no idea why this is getting so many downvotes. You are missing a $-\infty$ on the first limit of $f$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x) = \begin{cases} x+1, & x < -1,\\
0,& -1 \le x \le 1, \\
x-1, & x > 1\end{cases}$.

Note that $\{ t | f(t) <0 \} = (-\infty,-1)$.

Then $g(0)= -1$, but $g(x) = x+1$ for $x >0$.

Comment: how $g(0) =-1$  ?.im not getting @copper.hat

Comment: $g(0) =0$ ?? its  is correct ?

Comment: No, $g(0)=-1$. ${}{}$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 0):

No ,  $g $ need not be  continious

take $f(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x < 1,\\
-x+2,& 1 \le x \le 2, \\
x-2, & x > 2\end{cases}$.

Then  $g(x) = \begin{cases} x, & x \le 0,\\
x+2, & x > 0\end{cases}$.

graph :[image]